# Customizing app.config

Tags: .net, configuration, customization

I'd like to be able to extend `ConfigurationManager` so that I have an app.config some like the following:

```
<configuration>

<databases>
    <add name="db1" server="someServer" dbName="superDB" userName="" password=""/>
    <add name="db2" server="anotherServer" dbName="ordinaryDB" userName="dba" password="dba"/>
</databases>

</configuration>
```

And then to be able to access these fields via `ConfigurationManager` like so

```
string dbName = ConfigurationManager.Databases["db1"].DBName;
```

I've had a look at customization options available ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) for instance) but it doesn't really give me what I'm trying to achieve. Is this even possible?

(I realise that I could do this by rolling my own configuration manager but I'd really prefer to extend what the .NET framework currently offers if at all possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should use the [`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) property in this case.

If you really do want to extend the App.Config to contain your own configuration section(s) you can create a class that derives from [`ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) class.  There is a good example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx).

What you expressed in your question... to be able to do something like `ConfigurationManager.Databases`, where Databases is a custom static property on ConfigurationManager class, is not possible.

Comment: Good point about connect strings. It did not come to mind despite the fact that I would use the information I want configured to come up with effectively a set of connect strings. Whether or not defining connect strings is more difficult then simply specifying the server, db name, etc for the user is another question I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have create a custom configuration manager. You can do this by creating an custom configuration section, registering it in the config file and you're done.

Hope this helps...

Ps good tutorial @ codeproject.com : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx